# Joining two string variables in text file in Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have written the following code:

```
f = open('write.txt', "r")

N = open('n-gram.txt', "w")

B = open('buffer.txt', "w")

lines = f.readlines()

i = 0

for line1 in lines: 
 for line2 in lines:
   if line1 == line2:
     i = i + 1

 a = line1; b = str(i)

 y = ''.join(['%s: ','%s']) %(a, b)

 print y

 i = 0
```

My goal is to write a and b in one line of the file N. The program works perfectly only it writes `a` and `b` on two separate lines. The goal is that I get something like:

```
Line1: str(i)
```

Where `Line1` is a word and `str(i)` is a number (actually a string, but it looks like a number). Can you guys help me? I can`t seem to figure it out.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add python tag.

Comment: `a = line1.rstrip()` will fix your newline issue, but this code really should be re-factored entirely

Comment: Try to remove possible `\n` in the strings with `line.strip('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

When using f.readlines() method, basically the newline character is left for every line that is read except for the last line if it doesn't end with a newline character (Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Therefore, you should remove the newline character for each line.
You may use [rstrip](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm) method, which removes any whitespace characters as default.